# Change value of variable in all release definition

Tags: tfs, release, devops, tfs-2015

I am using a TFS 2015. 
In all release definitions (around 100) i have variable defined 'Databasename' with a value. Now I need to change its value for all release definition, so can you please tell me how can I accomplished this.
There is no varible group in TFS 2015. I have read multiple documents online but didnt find any solution.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on the REST APIs? You'll need to use those.

Comment: Can you please post the link of it

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure that tfs 2015 supports this version of rest api. But you may try it:

1. Get release definitions list: [Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Check this step first. Paste into your browser the url:

```
http://your_server:port/tfs/{collection_name}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=3.0
```

2. Get one release definition: [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
3. Update an existing release definition (variables member): [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

I`ve got definition for the release on my tfs 2015 server:
My release definition:

[image]

Json from TFS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to change every variable you want :

```js
$tfsUrl = "http://ServerName:Port/tfs/CollectionName/ProjectName"
$releaseDefurl = $tfsUrl + '/_apis/release/definitions?$expand=artifacts&api-version=3.2-preview.3'

$Env = "Environment Name"
$VariableName = "Variable Name"

$allreleaseDef = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($releaseDefurl) -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials).value |  Where-Object {$_.name -like "*Release Name*"} | select id,name

foreach ($release in $allreleaseDef)
{
    $ReleaseInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$tfsUrl/_apis/Release/definitions/$($release.id)" -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials

    ($ReleaseInfo.environments | where name -eq "$Env").variables.$VariableName.value = "NEW VALUE"

    $json  = $ReleaseInfo | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$tfsUrl/_apis/release/definitions/$($release.id)?api-version=3.2-preview.3" -Method Put -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json 

}
```